# Можно вывести значения из объекта как список?

Tags: javascript

```
var user1 = {
   name: 'Vasya',
   surname: 'Ivanov',
   age: 27,
   city: 'Moscow';
}
```

Через `alert(user1);` или `document.write(user1);`

Такое вообще возможно, или делается иначе?

Comment: какой результат то хотите увидеть?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var user1 = {
   name: 'Vasya',
   surname: 'Ivanov',
   age: 27,
   city: 'Moscow'
};

var content = [];
for (var key in user1) {
  content.push(key + ": " + user1[key]);
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = content.join("<br/>");
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

```js
var user1 = {
   name: 'Vasya',
   surname: 'Ivanov',
   age: 27,
   city: 'Moscow'
};

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
  Object.keys(user1).map(key => `${key}: ${user1[key]}`).join("<br/>");
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

```js
var user1 = {
   name: 'Vasya',
   surname: 'Ivanov',
   age: 27,
   city: 'Moscow'
};

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
  Object.keys(user1).reduce((res,key) => `${res}${key}: ${user1[key]}<br/>`, "");
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: тогда уж сразу `reduce`, вместо `map`/`join`

Comment: можно использовать es2017 Object.entries как я написал

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать es2017:

```js
const user1 = {
   name: 'Vasya',
   surname: 'Ivanov',
   age: 27,
   city: 'Moscow'
}

const result = Object.entries(user1).map(
  ([key, val]) => `${key}: ${val}`
).join('\n')

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = result
console.log(result)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Не понятно что конкретно нужно увидеть, но как вариант:

```js
var user1 = {
   name: 'Vasya',
   surname: 'Ivanov',
   age: 27,
   city: 'Moscow'
}
var result = JSON.stringify(user1, null, ' ')

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = result
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```